# Linux DDOS Protection / Gateway without NAT

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ddos

I need help to configure a box for DDOS protection and provide external ip addresses to "internal" (which aren't really internal) servers.
I have 32 IP addresses from my ISP.

I want to configure a linux box with DDOS protection and put servers behind that box. Everything using those IP addresses.
Something like this:

ISP   <--->      Anti-DDOS / Gateway  <--->    serverA/serverB/serverC/etc...
xx.xx.xx.190         xx.xx.xx.189              xx.xx.xx.171 -> xx.xx.xx.188

To be precise, i still didn't started to configure the boxes and i already found a similar topic here but for ipv6.

Note: The servers need to have the public ips configured (No NAT or private IPs are to be used).
Note 2: No, my ISP doesn't provide me a DDOS protection.

What you recomend for software and configuration? My operating systems are Linux Debian only but can use others OS (no windows please!)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. For example by making a Linux Bridge (follow [this](http://people.apache.org/~amc/tiphares/bridge.html) tutorial for a bit). Another way is (for example) making a loadbalancer with IPVS (you can then bind the external IPs on the loopback interface on each client).

Comment: Hello Jeroen. Thanks for your reply and suggestion.
On that Linux Bridge can i have some kind of DDOS protection? What do you recomend? Actually i am using iptables with some sort of packet analysis with conn_track on another box. But i see it's not fully efficient.

Comment: We have a dedicated (hardware) DDoS appliance for that, because it has custom ASICs. The problem with a linux box is that it will be limited on interrupts / cpu processing. I would recommend using a really good quality NIC and run irqbalance (if not already). However, it will never be able to reach the performance that a specialized appliance has. 


To block and detect attacks, you can either write something yourself with IPtables or use firewall packages (CSF). There are also commercial solutions like Clavister (software).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
But after having invested in so many dedicated servers, there's no more budget this year for a dedicated DDoS appliance. I can manage to make the bridge but i don't see how can i integrate the CSF (or any other) on that.